# 3D object Scaled while rotating y axis

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, gesture

I am new to OpenGL and ARCore and I am using [GoogleARCore Sample](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk) as a base to create my application. I am using OpenGL-ES-2.0 version. I able to do Pinch zoom (2 fingers) using `android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`. By using this library class of Rotation [Rotation Gesture](https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors) I am able to get my rotation degree and it worked well with my 3D Object.

While rotating my 3D object, my object gets scaled too. I want to stop my scaling while the user is doing the rotation. How can I achieve this? Or how can I pass my both scaling and rotation in a different method to update their respective matrix? I do not want to use any 3D party library for this.

Please help me with this. Below is my code and suggest me where I am doing anything wrong.

**ScaleGesture**

```
private class CustomScaleGesture extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            DebugHelper.log("detector.getScaleFactor(): " + detector.getScaleFactor() + " scaleFactor = " + scaleFactor);
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            DebugHelper.log("final scaleFactor: " + scaleFactor);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**RotationGesture**

```
private class RotateListener extends RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
            DebugHelper.log("RotateListener called..");
            mRotationDegrees -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
            DebugHelper.log("RotateListener: " + mRotationDegrees);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MyARActivity extends BaseActivity<MyActivityArBinding> implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {


    //AR Variables
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private boolean capturePicture = false;
    private boolean installRequested;
    private boolean moving;
    float[] projmtx = new float[16];
    float[] viewmtx = new float[16];
    private Session session;

    private Snackbar messageSnackbar;
    private DisplayRotationHelper displayRotationHelper;
    private final BackgroundRenderer backgroundRenderer = new BackgroundRenderer();
    private ObjectRenderer virtualObject;
    private ObjectRenderer virtualObjectShadow;
    private final PlaneRenderer planeRenderer = new PlaneRenderer();
    private PointCloudRenderer pointCloud = new PointCloudRenderer();

    // Temporary matrix allocated here to reduce number of allocations for each frame.
    private float[] anchorMatrix = new float[16];
    // Tap handling and UI.
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<MotionEvent> queuedSingleTaps = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(16);
    private ArrayList<Anchor> anchors = new ArrayList<>();

    //load and manipulate obj
    private SQLiteHelper sqlHelper;
    private boolean isObjectChanged = false;
    private String objectPath;
    private List<CharacterModel> characterModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isFirstTimeLoad = true;
    //Gestures
    private float mRotationDegrees = 0.f;
    private RotateGestureDetector mRotateDetector;
    private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHeaderVisible(false);
        doDefaults();
    }

    private void doDefaults() {
        binding.setPresenter(this);
        sqlHelper = SQLiteHelper.getInstance(this);
        load3DCharacters();
        initAR();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void initAR() {
        displayRotationHelper = new DisplayRotationHelper(this);
        scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new CustomScaleGesture());
        mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new RotateListener());

        // Set up tap listener.
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                if (anchors.size() <= 0) {
                    onSingleTap(e);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        binding.surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                DebugHelper.log("binding.surfaceView.setOnTouchListener called..");
                mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        moving = true;
                        DebugHelper.log("ACTION_DOWN");
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        DebugHelper.log("ACTION_UP");
                        moving = false;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        DebugHelper.log("ACTION_MOVE");
                        if (anchors.size() > 0) {
                            onSecondTouch(event);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            }
        });

        // Set up renderer.
        binding.surfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        binding.surfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        binding.surfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); // Alpha used for plane blending.
        binding.surfaceView.setRenderer(this);
        binding.surfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
        installRequested = false;
    }
    private void onSecondTouch(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("Second Touch", "Executed");
        if (e.getPointerCount() > 1) {
            scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        } else {
            queuedSingleTaps.offer(e);
        }
    }
private void onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // Queue tap if there is space. Tap is lost if queue is full.
        DebugHelper.log("onSingleTap()");
        queuedSingleTaps.offer(e);
    }

    private void load3DCharacters() {
        CharacterModel model = new CharacterModel();
        model.setName("Cat");
        model.setObjectPath("cat/cat.obj");
        model.setScaleFactor(0.25f);
        model.setResourceId(R.drawable.cat);
        characterModelList.add(model);

        model = new CharacterModel();
        model.setName("Old Man");
        model.setObjectPath("man/muro.obj");
        model.setScaleFactor(0.0085f);
        model.setResourceId(R.drawable.old_man);
        characterModelList.add(model);


        model = new CharacterModel();
        model.setName("Bloodwing");
        model.setObjectPath("bloodwing/bloodwing.obj");
        model.setScaleFactor(0.0009f);
        model.setResourceId(R.drawable.bat);
        characterModelList.add(model);
    }

    private void loadObject(CharacterModel model) {
        try {
            this.objectPath = model.getObjectPath();
            this.scaleFactor = model.getScaleFactor();
            if (virtualObject == null) {
                virtualObject = new ObjectRenderer(objectPath);
                virtualObject.createOnGlThread(this);
                virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 6.0f);
            } else {
                // Clear screen to notify driver it should not load any pixels from previous frame.
                GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                isObjectChanged = true;
                virtualObject.updateObjectPath(model.getObjectPath());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


@Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (isObjectChanged) {
            isObjectChanged = false;
            try {
                virtualObject.createOnGlThread(this);
                virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.5f, 6.0f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }

        // Clear screen to notify driver it should not load any pixels from previous frame.
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Notify ARCore session that the view size changed so that the perspective matrix and
        // the video background can be properly adjusted.
        displayRotationHelper.updateSessionIfNeeded(session);

        try {
            session.setCameraTextureName(backgroundRenderer.getTextureId());

            // Obtain the current frame from ARSession. When the configuration is set to
            // UpdateMode.BLOCKING (it is by default), this will throttle the rendering to the
            // camera framerate.
            Frame frame = session.update();
            Camera camera = frame.getCamera();

            // Handle taps. Handling only one tap per frame, as taps are usually low frequency
            // compared to frame rate.
            MotionEvent tap = queuedSingleTaps.poll();
            if (tap != null && camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                for (HitResult hit : frame.hitTest(tap)) {
                    // Check if any plane was hit, and if it was hit inside the plane polygon
                    Trackable trackable = hit.getTrackable();
                    // Creates an anchor if a plane or an oriented point was hit.
                    if ((trackable instanceof Plane && ((Plane) trackable).isPoseInPolygon(hit.getHitPose())) || (trackable instanceof Point && ((Point) trackable).getOrientationMode() == Point.OrientationMode.ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL)) {
                        // Hits are sorted by depth. Consider only closest hit on a plane or oriented point.
                        // Cap the number of objects created. This avoids overloading both the
                        // rendering system and ARCore.
                        //if (!isUpdate) {
                        DebugHelper.log("Anchor size = " + anchors.size());
                        if (anchors.size() >= 1) {
                            anchors.get(0).detach();
                            anchors.remove(0);
                        }
                        // Adding an Anchor tells ARCore that it should track this position in
                        // space. This anchor is created on the Plane to place the 3D model
                        // in the correct position relative both to the world and to the plane.
                        if (anchors.size() > 0) {
                            DebugHelper.log("anchor list has data");
                            for (Anchor anchor : anchors) {
                                anchor.detach();
                                anchors.remove(anchor);
                            }
                        }
                        Anchor anchor = hit.createAnchor();
                        if (anchor != null)
                            anchors.add(anchor);
                        else
                            DebugHelper.log("anchor is null");
                        //}
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Draw background.
            backgroundRenderer.draw(frame);

            // If not tracking, don't draw 3d objects.
            if (camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.PAUSED) {
                return;
            }

            // Get projection matrix.
            camera.getProjectionMatrix(projmtx, 0, 0.1f, 100.0f);

            // Get camera matrix and draw.
            camera.getViewMatrix(viewmtx, 0);

            // Compute lighting from average intensity of the image.
            final float lightIntensity = frame.getLightEstimate().getPixelIntensity();

            // Visualize tracked points.
            PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
            this.pointCloud.update(pointCloud);
            if (!capturePicture)
                this.pointCloud.draw(viewmtx, projmtx);

            // Application is responsible for releasing the point cloud resources after
            // using it.
            pointCloud.release();

            // Check if we detected at least one plane. If so, hide the loading message.
            if (messageSnackbar != null) {
                {
                    for (Plane plane : session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                        if (plane.getType() == Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
                                && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                            hideLoadingMessage();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (Plane plane : session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                    if (plane.getType() == Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                        hideLoadingMessage();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Visualize planes.
            if (!capturePicture)
                planeRenderer.drawPlanes(session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class), camera.getDisplayOrientedPose(), projmtx);

            // Visualize anchors created by touch.
            for (Anchor anchor : anchors) {
                if (anchor.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    continue;
                }
                // Get the current pose of an Anchor in world space. The Anchor pose is updated
                // during calls to session.update() as ARCore refines its estimate of the world.
                anchor.getPose().toMatrix(anchorMatrix, 0);

                // Update and draw the model and its shadow.
                if (virtualObject != null) {
//passing my scaleFector and rotationDegree to update my matrix.
                    virtualObject.updateModelMatrix(anchorMatrix, scaleFactor, mRotationDegrees);
                    if (viewmtx != null && projmtx != null) {
                        virtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
                    }
                }

            }

            if (capturePicture) {
                capturePicture = false;
                onSavePicture();
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception on the OpenGL thread", t);
        }
    }
```

**ObjectRenderer**

```
 public void draw(float[] cameraView, float[] cameraPerspective, float lightIntensity) {
        try {
            ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "Before draw");
Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelViewMatrix, 0, cameraView, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, cameraPerspective, 0, mModelViewMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, MyARActivity.rotationDegrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //rotation degree pass to matrix
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

            // Set the lighting environment properties.
            Matrix.multiplyMV(mViewLightDirection, 0, mModelViewMatrix, 0, LIGHT_DIRECTION, 0);
            normalizeVec3(mViewLightDirection);
            GLES20.glUniform4f(mLightingParametersUniform, mViewLightDirection[0], mViewLightDirection[1], mViewLightDirection[2], lightIntensity);

            // Set the object material properties.
            GLES20.glUniform4f(mMaterialParametersUniform, mAmbient, mDiffuse, mSpecular, mSpecularPower);

            // Set the ModelViewProjection matrix in the shader.
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewUniform, 1, false, mModelViewMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewProjectionUniform, 1, false, mModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewProjectionUniform, 1, false, mFinalModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);

            if (mBlendMode != null) {
                GLES20.glDepthMask(false);
                GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
                switch (mBlendMode) {
                    case Shadow:
                        // Multiplicative blending function for Shadow.
                        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ZERO, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
                        break;
                    case Grid:
                        // Grid, additive blending function.
                        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (mObj != null && mObj.getNumMaterialGroups() > 0) {
                //Start drawing data from each VAO
                for (int i = 0; i < mObj.getNumMaterialGroups(); i++) {
                    // Attach the object texture.
                    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniform, 0);
                    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[i]);

                    GLES30.glBindVertexArray(vectorArrayObjectIds[i]);
                    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, mObj.getMaterialGroup(i).getNumFaces() * 3,
                            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
                    GLES30.glBindVertexArray(0);

                    //Unbind texture
                    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
                }
            }

            if (mBlendMode != null) {
                GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
                GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
            }

            ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "After draw");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```